# Handling leaf node in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I am creating a nested list using sencha. 
Now on tap i get a list it goes on till i get to the leaf node.

Now what i want is, on clicking a leaf node, i want to generate an event which enables me to open a file.

Not sure how to do that.

my nested list code is

```
Ext.define("InfoImage.view.nestedList", {
    extend:'Ext.NestedList',
    xtype:'nestedList',
    id:'nestedList',

    config:{
        fullscreen:'true',
        title:'Nested List',
        xtype:'nestedList',
        displayField : 'text',
        html:'Nested List on its way!!!',
        store:'nestedListStore'
        //itemTpl:'{text}'
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open a file? Which file? Where it is located?

Comment: Any file located on the system.

Comment: File located on the system? I don't think, native feature like file accessing comes with SenchaTouch. Sencha Touch is for UI, not native functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the event: "onleafitemtap" provided by the nested list.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your require PhoneGap here.

File System Access is not available with Sencha Touch. So, you need to use phonegap's File API to access and read the file stored on the system.

Check out the [**File API Documentation**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File),

```
FILE API : An API to read, write and navigate file system hierarchies.
```

Sample e.g from Phonegap,

```
 ...
 ...
// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

...
...
```

Hope that helps you!